# Поменять локаль во время работы приложения при изменении значения JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, locale

У меня есть фрейм, на котором лежат всякие JComponent'ы. У меня есть JComboBox со списком локалей. При изменении его значения я хочу изменить все кнопки, все лэйблы в соответствии с локалью. Понятное дело, что пишется это всё в ActionListener. Но что туда написать? Как обновить все значения в соответствии с локалью сразу же?

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял твою проблему, тебе нужно получить все элементы и установить им нужное свойство.. Думаю, это можно сделать так:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for(Component component : frame.getComponents()) {
       component.setLocale(locale);
    }
    frame.repaint();
}
```